# how do I use async await in a regular for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I have a function that accepts a game found from a mongodb database via mongoose and the number of bots to add to the game object. the problem is after running the function only one bot object is being saved to the document even thought `numOfBots` is 3

```
async function addBot(game, numOfBots){

  for(index = 0; index < numOfBots; index++){
    let bot = {nickName: "Bot"}
    game.players.push(bot)
    game = await game.save()
  }
  return game
}

// elsewhere in another async function 
await addBot(game,3)
```

How can I use async await correctly in a regular for loop?

Comment: Why not save the `game` only once, after you put all the bots in its `.players` list?

Comment: What does `game.save()` return?

Comment: Your `index` variable is [accidentally global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Don't forget to declare it, and always run your code in strict mode. Anything might be happening in that loop if you call the function (or other functions using the same `index`) multiple times concurrently.

Comment: I don’t think this is an issue with async await. There is an issue with the mongoose setup.

Comment: declare the index value

Comment: you are right. After fixing that mistake of not declaring it as well as only saving it after the loop it added the document 3 times but I get a "Can't save() the same document multiple times in parallel error. Never mind it's an unrelated issue. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: @AmirrezaFelfelian Not really, no. OP is not having trouble with `forEach` but with mongodb